# Problema en el redireccionamiento usando wodrpress

Tags: html, html5, wordpress, redirección

Tengo un problema al usar el siguiente codigo html en mi pagina web hecha en wordpress

```
<li><a href="www.twitter.com" class="icoTwitter" title="Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
</li>
```

Lo que pienso es hacer un redireccionamiento a la pagina de twitter pero cuando le doy al boton me envia a mipaginaweb/www.twitter.com y me sale la siguiente pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿por qué sucede ésto?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tienes un error sencillo, para poder colocar un enlace fuera de tu web debes colocarle el

> https://

entonces quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```html
<li><a href="https://twitter.com" class="icoTwitter" title="Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
</li>
```